# Fetching URL data and looping through it to push it to a component's state array - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, components, this

So I've started to learn ReactJS recently, and been struggling with handling a component's state.
While fetching an URL, I receive a JSON file and set the state of my component to have values based on this JSON file. I have no problem doing that if my state's key only receives one value, but I can't figure out how to loop through my setState so I can return multiple values to one of my state keys.
For example, if the JSON has an array of ingredients, I can only pass one ingredient to my state ingredients array, and not all of them.
In sum, I want to do something like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < json.ingredients.length; i++) {
  this.setState({
    ingredients: [...this.state.ingredients, json.ingredients[i].name]
  })
}
```

This is the code I used to create my component so far:

```
class SingleMeal extends Component {
state = {
    meal: null,
    diets: [],
    ingredients: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const url = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${id}/information?apiKey='apiKey`;
    fetch(url)
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then ( json => (
       this.setState({ 
        meal: json,
        diets: json.diets[0], // ADD ALL DIETS TO THIS STATE OBJECT
        ingredients: [json.extendedIngredients[0].name]  // ADD ALL INGREDIENTS TO THIS STATE OBJECT
       })
    ))
}
```

I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1):

it you want to add all the items in json.diets, and select only the names from the json.extendedIngredients, try this:

```
this.setState({ 
        meal: json,
        diets: json.diets,
        ingredients: json.extendedIngredients.map(ingredient=>ingredient.name)  
       })
```

Also, I hope that isn't your actual api key in the url

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out my api key was posted, I didn't notice when copy and pasting it from my file.